# On clicking Command Button, copying and pasting data of same range from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, commandbutton

I want to create a Command Button clicking on which 4 copy-paste functions are performed one after another as under:

First Function: Data of Range A1:J500 are copied from sheet "Data3" and paste in the same range of Sheet "Data4". Then,
Second Function: Data of Range A1:J500 are copied from sheet "Data2" and paste in the same range of Sheet "Data3". Then,
Third Function: Data of Range A1:J500 are copied from sheet "Data1" and paste in the same range of Sheet "Data2". Then,
Last Function: Data of Range A1:J500 are copied from sheet "Data" and paste in the same range of Sheet "Data1"

I will appreciate your help in providing me with the code that I can use inside:

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
????
End Sub

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We would like to help you, but please let us know, what you have done so far and what kind of problem encountered.

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into difficulties. When that happens, you can explain the problem you've encountered, include the relevant portions of your code in the form of a [mre], and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll try to help. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Answer (score 1):

Simply record the task (record macro option ) of copy.
Assign the code to any desired button or object.

Reference: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html